# Find folders with as equal number of underlying files as possible

Tags: algorithm

How to write or approach the following problem:

Having N file paths as input (with maximum length M), located in K different folders (nested at any level) find L (where L <= K) tree root folders which contains equal (or as equal as possible) number of underlying files. Input paths are absolute, e.g.

```
/folderA/file1
/folderA/folderB/file2
/folderA/folderB/file3
/folderA/folderB/folderC/file4
/folderD/file5
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stuck at the very beginning. But this question is more about the direction I should take and evaluating the feasibility, rather than expecting the actual solution. I guess I could take count of all files and take greedy approach, which might be very inaccurate. Thinking about best solution it occurs to me it would be O(N!).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of pointers to get you started:

1. Since you need to group folders hierarchically, tree would be a suitable data structure to use
2. Each file path can be added to the tree (so the file becomes a leaf in the tree)
3. Number of files in a folder would be equal to the number of nodes in the subtree of that folder

Using these ideas, it should be easy for you to come up with a solution.